# Asp.net Core dependency injection in filters without [ServiceFilter] or [TypeFilter]

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

I need to inject some services with dependency injection to action filters. I'm familiar with the `[ServiceFilter]` and `[TypeFilter]` approach, but it's kind of ugly, messy, and unclear.

Is there a way I can set a filter in the normal way? without wrapping the filter I'm using with `[ServiceFilter]` or `[TypeFilter]`?

For example what I want:

```
[SomeFilterWithDI]
[AnotherFilterWithDI("some value")]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View("Index");
}
```

Instead of:

```
[ServiceFilter(typeof(SomeFilterWithDI))]
[TypeFilter(typeof(AnotherFilterWithDI), Arguments = new string[] { "some value" })]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View("Index");
}
```

It looks way different, this approach doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: Does your filter use DI ? Also what you mean by "Normal way" ?

Comment: @Shyju Yes, it does use DI. "Normal way" - I mean without the [ServiceFilter] and [TypeFilter] wrapping the filter I'm using.

Comment: That is the way to use it if yo have DI in your filer. I consider that as the "normal way"

Comment: There can't be any other way. DI/IoC Containers are no black magic. Attributes by its very nature must be instantiated with know parameters (**parameters must be know at compile time** - this is a CIL/language limitation), this means only constants. Of course you can access `context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IMyService>();` within the OnActionXxx method, but that's not a lot cleaner neither and of course, it's not called **dependency injection** anymore

Comment: You can implement [`IFilterFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.1#ifilterfactory-implemented-on-your-attribute) for your *first* example (with no parameters).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For `[SomeFilterWithDI]`, you could refer the comment from @Kirk larkin.

For `[AnotherFilterWithDI("some value")]`, you could try passing `Arguments` from `TypeFilterAttribute`.

- `ParameterTypeFilter` define the accept parameters.

  ```
  public class ParameterTypeFilter: TypeFilterAttribute
  {

      public ParameterTypeFilter(string para1, string para2):base(typeof(ParameterActionFilter))
      {
          Arguments = new object[] { para1, para2 };
      }
  }
  ```
- `ParameterActionFilter` accept the passed parameters.

  ```
      public class ParameterActionFilter : IActionFilter
  {
      private readonly ILogger _logger;
      private readonly string _para1;
      private readonly string _para2;

      public ParameterActionFilter(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, string para1, string para2)
      {
          _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<ParameterTypeFilter>();
          _para1 = para1;
          _para2 = para2;
      }

      public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
      {
          _logger.LogInformation($"Parameter One is {_para1}");
          // perform some business logic work

      }

      public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
      {
          // perform some business logic work
          _logger.LogInformation($"Parameter Two is {_para2}");
      }
  }
  ```

  As the description from `Arguments`, `ILoggerFactory loggerFactory` is resolved by `dependency injection container`. `para1` and `para2` is resolved by `ParameterTypeFilter`.

  ```
      //
  // Summary:
  //     Gets or sets the non-service arguments to pass to the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TypeFilterAttribute.ImplementationType
  //     constructor.
  //
  // Remarks:
  //     Service arguments are found in the dependency injection container i.e. this filter
  //     supports constructor injection in addition to passing the given Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TypeFilterAttribute.Arguments.
  public object[] Arguments { get; set; }
  ```
- Useage

  ```
  [ParameterTypeFilter("T1","T2")]
  public ActionResult Parameter()
  {
      return Ok("Test");
  }
  ```